# Hide parent check box in ivh-treeview angularjs plugin

Tags: html, angularjs

[image]

My Html Code is

```
    <div ivh-treeview="menuPermissionObj.generalAssetManagement"
         ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="-1" 

         ivh-treeview-on-cb-change="changeCallback(ivhNode,ivhIsSelected, ivhTree)">

</div>
```

i used this plugin

https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview

is there any way to hide parent checkbox?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to use a custom node template.

See the list of supported helper methods and scope variables in your templates here: https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/docs/templates-and-skins.md#supported-template-scope-variables

Both `isLeaf(node)` and the `depth` variable will pair well with `ng-show`.